# windows store app read and display image from ziparchive without uncompressing files

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

am trying to show image directly from zip file without extracting file.

```
  ZipArchiveEntry tumbnail = archive.Entries.Where(s => s.FullName.Equals("coverthumb.png")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (tumbnail != null)
            {                   
                Stream picdata = tumbnail.Open();                 
                await picdata.CopyToAsync (picdata);
                BitmapImage bt = new BitmapImage();                     
                bt.SetSource (picdata.AsRandomAccessStream());
                image.Source = bt;       
            }
```

but getting an

> cannot seek exception

please help.

Answer (score 0):

the following code works for images but when tries to read many images at once some times it gives invalid data exception at bitmap creation

```
 async public static Task<BitmapImage> GetImageFromZipEntry(ZipArchiveEntry zipentry)
    {
        //for extracting image inside a zip as bitmapimage
        BitmapImage tm = new BitmapImage();
        try {
            if (zipentry != null)
            {
                using (Stream imstream = zipentry.Open())
                {


                    using (MemoryStream immemorystream = new MemoryStream((int)zipentry.Length))
                    {

                        await imstream.CopyToAsync(immemorystream);
                        using (var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(immemorystream.ToArray()))
                        {

                            await tm.SetSourceAsync(sourceStream.AsRandomAccessStream());


                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            tm = null;
        }
        return tm;

    }
```